# What regulates cyclic AMP?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, cell-membrane, cell-signaling, receptor

After reading a textbook chapter on GPCRs I am still confused by what regulates cAMP.

I took in my notes that cAMP is made by adenylyl cyclase and destroyed by cAMP phosphodiesterases (also another question within a question, are phosphodiesterases the same as phosphatases?)

So is cAMP regulated by GPCRs or is it regulated by cyclic AMP dependent Kinase A (PKA)?

I did find this article, but I'm not sure if I am understanding this correctly to answer my own question, but it seems like they are saying GPCRs regulate cAMP?

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2720142/

Thanks

Comment: Phosphodiesterases are not necessarily the same as the phosphatases. A [phosphodiester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphodiester_bond) has 2 ester linkages, like in DNA. So a phosphatase could specifically cut off phosphates with a single ester linkage while ignoring the phosphodiesters.

Comment: Have you consulted a basic biochemistry text such as Berg et al (available on NCBI Bookshelf)? Start there.

Comment: Not helpful as you do not provide a direct answer to my question or even provide the link to the text you are referencing. Here is a google search of Berg et al:
https://www.google.com/search?ei=v46SXPWTNqqMggeL4ZUo&q=berg+et+al&oq=berg+et+al&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0l9.3621.4609..5211...0.0..0.92.752.10......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0i131j0i20i263j0i10i67j0i10.4283tGmD09U